# C++ Declaring a variable with the ternary operator

Tags: c++, declaration, conditional-operator

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this. (i know it's really weird ^^)

```cpp
bool B(true);
std::vector< (B == true) ? bool : int > v;
```

Comment: Is `B` known at compile-time or only at runtime?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Mhmm i don't know. I put B in the function main. And yes i tried it but i have this error : error: template argument 1 is invalid

Answer (score 4):

```
constexpr bool B(true);
std::vector< std::conditional_t <B == true, bool , int >> v;
```

Comment: `B == true` -> `B` ? or did you spell it out on purpose?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Not needed, I just copy-paste and make a 2s edit!

Comment: ofc not needed, its just "nicer"

Comment: I have to include which library ?

Comment: @user13286774 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Comment: @user13286774 <type_traits>